# Trouble importing pygame

Tags: python, import, module, pygame, python-idle

After running import pygame in IDLE Python 3.7.2 and have now tried in Anaconda spyder and get exactly the same error

```
   import pygame: Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

In terminal when I run pip3 install pygame:

```
  pip3 install pygame
   Requirement already satisfied:
   pygame in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.9.4)
```

After running sys.path in IDLE Python 3.7.2

```
['', '/Users/myname/Documents', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

So I'm guessing there are several versions of python installed on the system and the pygame is in 3.7/site-packages.

How can I get pygame to work in Idle python 3.7.2?

Answer (score 1):

Now solved:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages')
>>> import pygame
pygame 1.9.4
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
>>>
```